# How do I return a value from this function if I am determining the return value with a for loop?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I want to make a typescript function that I can reuse in my cloud functions. The function below should return a 1 if the username is not taken or a 0 if it is taken. However, the code below is showing an error (noted below). I assume this is because of scope. But I don't understand how to use the for loop to determine if the user is available or not and then return that value.

I also tried simply doing a `return` in the `if...else...`, but then the function was saying that I was returning `Promise<Void>`, which I don't want. I need this to return a 1 or a 0.

```
//Check if username is available (callable from backend only)
async function isUsernameAvailable(username: String): Promise<Number> {
  const qData = await admin.firestore().collection('users').where('username', '==', username).limit(1).get()
  var returnVal: Number
  qData.docs.forEach(doc => {
    const targetUsername = doc.get('username').toString();
    var val: Number
    console.log('_isUsernameAvailable_targetUsername: ', targetUsername);
    if (username == targetUsername) {
      console.log('_isUsernameAvailable username: ', username, 'targetUsername: ', targetUsername);
      val = 0;
    } else {
      console.log('_isUsernameAvailable username: ', username, 'targetUsername: ', targetUsername);
      val = 1;
    };
  });
  returnVal = val //Error is here: Cannot find name 'val'
  return val //Another error here: Cannot find name 'val'
};
```

Comment: Define the val outside of forEach. It should work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to *declare* the `val` variable outside of the loop, so that `return val` can find it:

```
//Check if username is available (callable from backend only)
async function isUsernameAvailable(username: String): Promise<Number> {
  const qData = await admin.firestore().collection('users').where('username', '==', username).limit(1).get()
  let val: Number
  qData.docs.forEach(doc => {
    const targetUsername = doc.get('username').toString();
    console.log('_isUsernameAvailable_targetUsername: ', targetUsername);
    if (username == targetUsername) {
      console.log('_isUsernameAvailable username: ', username, 'targetUsername: ', targetUsername);
      val = 0;
    } else {
      console.log('_isUsernameAvailable username: ', username, 'targetUsername: ', targetUsername);
      val = 1;
    };
  });
  return val
};
```

---

After a chat with Jake in the comments: you don't even need the loop, and can just:

```
async function isUsernameAvailable(username: String): Promise<Number> {
  const qData = await admin.firestore().collection('users').where('username', '==', username).limit(1).get()
  return qData.exists ? 1 : 0
};
```

Or by returning a boolean, it can be even simpler:

```
async function isUsernameAvailable(username: String): Promise<boolean> {
  const qData = await admin.firestore().collection('users').where('username', '==', username).limit(1).get()
  return qData.exists
};
```

Comment: This fixes the error, but likely doesn't do what is expected. This will always return `1` unless the `username` matches the `targetUsername` in the last array element. A `for-of` loop would probably work better, or use `Array.prototype.some` with a return value check.

Comment: I don't think the `if` is needed at all, as you're already querying for `where('username', '==', username)`. Give it a try.

Comment: I am not the question asker, just noting something that looked problematic. You're right though, the query should be doing the work here, they probably just need to check that the returned array has 1 element.

Comment: Yup, in further looking at the code - the entire loop isn't needed, but it could just be `return  qData.exists ? 1 : 0`. Or even just `return qData.exists` and make the return type a `Promise<boolean>`.